# Modifying an item in an arraylist coding issue

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

I am trying to change values of items in my arraylist. I can't seem to get this working. I am at a loss as to how to really ask this question. The code is quite extensive (or at least it is in my book) so I can't really show all of it. However if I know the current index, how can I make it change the ItemName?

```
 currentIndex.setItemName(newItemName);
```

CurrentIndex is an int that tells me which index I am at, ItemName is a string that is in my arraylist. Should I be getting the ItemName prior to trying to set it? Something like this

```
InventoryItem.getItemName();
currentIndex.setItemName(newItemName);
```

This also does not work.

Edit: I was asked to show more code. Here is the panel that pops up in my action listener

```
 modifyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JTextField xField = new JTextField(15);
            JTextField yField = new JTextField(15);
            JTextField zField = new JTextField(15);

            JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("Item Name:"));
            myPanel.add(xField);

            myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("Number in inventory:"));
            myPanel.add(yField);

            myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); // a spacer
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("Unit Price:"));
            myPanel.add(zField);
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
                    "Please Enter data into all boxes", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

                String newItemName = String.valueOf(xField);
                String text1 = yField.getText();
                String newInventoryAmount = String.valueOf(text1);
                int newAmount = Integer.parseInt(newInventoryAmount);
                String text2 = zField.getText();
                String newUnitPrice = String.valueOf(text2);
                double newPrice = Double.parseDouble(newUnitPrice);
                inventory.get(currentIndex).setItemName(newItemName);
                inventory.get(currentIndex).setInStock(newAmount);
                inventory.get(currentIndex).setUnitPrice(newPrice);


            }
        }

}

);
```

Comment: What's the name of your `ArrayList`?

Comment: I have also tried something like `inventory.set(itemName = newItemName);` but that can't seem to find the itemName. I think that is because it is in a seperate class?

Comment: `public static ArrayList<InventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ìnt` doesn't have a method `setItemName` (or any method at all, since it's a primitive, not an object).

Try `yourArrayList.get(currentIndex).setItemName(newItemName);`

It calls `setItemName` on the desired element of the list.

EDIT: to fix your new problem, replace `String newItemName = String.valueOf(xField);` with

```
String newItemName = xField.getText();
```

I believe this is what you want to do.

Comment: This works but when I go to look at the new value it says Item Name = javax.awing.JTextField( ... and doesn't seem to actually change it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your ArrayList is name so I'll just call it arrayList.

Try

```
arrayList.get(currentIndex).setItemName(newItemName);
```

`arrayList.get(currentIndex)` calls the element from your list at the current index

That allows you to use `.setItemName(newItemName)` to change the name of the object.

Comment: That's seems confusing. Maybe just call it arrayList.

Comment: Yes, at least give it a name that could theoretically be correct.

Answer (score 1):

`list.set(index, newItemName)`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int, E)

Comment: `set` changes the object reference, it's no good for mutating an object in the list without replacing it.

Comment: But he said the string is in his array list and he is trying to change it. The string is immutable so the only way is to set it in the list.

Comment: String immutability doesn't mean that you can't replace a String reference in an object.

Comment: Which is what set does.... He said his list contains the strings directly - so he doesn't have an object to modify.

Comment: Never mind, I just saw his comment and he does have an object to set the name on :)

Comment: This works for all items that I am trying to modify except for the string. I managed to get this to work for item price and units in stock, but gives me a funny problem with the name. See my comment on kviiri's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code that accomplishes what I think you are trying to do.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ArrayList<Employee> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setName("Juan");

        myArrayList.add(e1);

        myArrayList.get(0).setName("Jhon");

        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(0).getName());


    }

}

class Employee {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```